# ODBC driver for Oracle on Windows 7 x64 disappearing

Tags: windows, oracle

I have a windows 7 x64 enterprise instance that I need to install the ODBC drivers for Oracle on.  When I run the Odbcad32.exe from %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\ it allows me to install the drivers.  However, when I close the ODBC Data Source Administrator and reopen it they are gone. I can't get them to stay.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

With `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe` you administer the 32bit ODBC Drivers. For 64bit drivers you have to use `%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`

Check carefully which one you call and what kind of driver you install.